# What is a back-merge

Tags: git, git-flow

I’ve watched some videos on the git-flow scripts and one term that comes up is “back merge” - e.g. hotfix is merged into master and back merged into develop.

I’m assuming back merge is a concept and not a native git command. What exact commands comprise a back merge operation?

Comment: Here's a little [Stack Overflow essay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65239988/341994) on this topic that might help folks to visualize why a "back merge" is needed after a hotfix.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The use of the term "back merge" is usually somewhat arbitrary.

It just means to do a merge, like any other, but in a direction that is "backwards" compared to the normal flow of the branching conventions.  If you visualize branches arranged like

```
master    hotfix    release    dev    feature
  |          |         |        |         |
  |          |         |        |         |
  |          |         |        |         |
  |          |         |        |         |
```

then changes normally "flow" from right to left - feature to dev to release to master.  But while hotfixes are pretty far left - they get created from master - they still have to be merged "to the right" into `dev`, so some people describe that as merging backwards, or back-merging.

In my opinion, that's not the most compelling use of the term, because it can be read to imply that the opposite merge (from dev to a hotfix branch) were a "forward merge" - but in fact that's something that shouldn't be done.  In this case the direction being "backward" is more about the general flow of changes if you visualize the branches in a particular way as above.

A more compelling use of the term is when you have a long-lived feature branch (which itself is something of an anti-pattern in agile processes that are likely to use gitflow; but sometimes you may need one).  In that case you periodically should update your long-lived feature from dev, so that the two don't deviate too much leading to a disaster of a merge conflict later.  (And this opens up a whole can of worms about "unnecessary" merges, what makes a good history, and `git rerere`... but I digress.)  *That* can clearly be called a back-merge because the opposite - merging your feature in to dev - is a normal, textbook use of merge in the branch model.

Answer (score 30):

Backmerge is nothing but **add your hotfix changes into your current working branch.**

Let's say you have two branches **Develop** and **Master**
You found any major bug on **Master**.
You fixed it on Master branch  itself as a **hotfix**.
Later you need to add your bugfix change into your **current working branch** i.e Develop branch.
so you need to do **back-merge** like this

---

1. git checkout Develop
2. git merge Master
3. git push origin Develop

Comment: yes, so we simply create a PR like: [ base: Develop <--- compare: MASTER ]. Usually you develop & implement code changes in Develop branch & push them to Master, But in such exceptional scenario of "HotFix", usually a hotfix is a breaking/blocking/critcal code change that saves our day. In this scenario time is vital constraint. Hence, you can't go from Devlop -> Test -> Stage -> Master, instead you make a code change directly on Master & then you do the backmerge, so that other branches are aware of the code change that their successor has.

Answer (score 9):

It's just two ordinary merge commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
git checkout develop
git merge hotfix
```

You can think of the "normal" flow of commits being from your development branch to `master` as the work is completed. In a back-merge, the commits are flowing in the opposite direction, from `hotfix` *into* your development branch.

Comment: Generally the last command would actually be `git merge master` (you're "back merging" master back into develop). As others have pointed out, it's an inexact term, but the way I've seen it used.

Comment: This one makes the most sense for me, but instead of `git merge hotfix`, replace with `git merge release` to merge a release branch with the Develop branch

Comment: The first two commands `git checkout master` and `git merge hotfix` is the normal flow. (sending something to production)
The last two commands `git checkout develop` and `git merge hotfix` is the back merge flow. (getting something back from hotfix)