# How to resolve a pull request conflicts in an azure repository?

Tags: git, azure, pull-request

I have a problem resolving two conflicts.

I did a pull request, the reviewer asked me to correct some lines of code, I corrected them then, I pushed my code and then I found two pull request conflicts in two files, I don't know how to fix that because I don't know where is the conflicts, I just know the files, i open them, I do not see anything, just regular files, I made changes in them and pushed it.

[image]

How to just resolve that, because I don't know, I never did it before.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to locally merge the branch you're trying to pull request into (also known as "back-merging")?

Comment: I did not understand what are you talking about !

Comment: aah, meaning I have to pull master ( the branch pulling request to ), before that ?

Comment: Yes :) You will get the conflict locally, and then you'll be able to solve them locally, push the merged version, and open a PR without conflicts. Read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555448/what-is-a-back-merge